# Proton-antiproton collisions

Tags: particle-physics, antimatter

I have read in lots of different articles that when protons and antiprotons collide, they produce lots of different particles, but mainly (charged) pions. Why is this? Why are they more likely to produce pions than any other particle?

Comment: Pions are the lightest hadron *by a Lot*! So the energy of the hadronic fireball is combinatorially much more likely to distribute itself into small packets.

Comment: See the statistical hadronization model (DOI) 10.1007/s100520100869 . Statistical equilibrium is an intrinsic feature of the hadronization process and hadrons are directly created in such a state  as was envisaged by Hagedorn.